# Connect Samsung e250 and computer over USB

Tags: java, connection, usb, symbian

I have developed two applications: first works on Samsung e250, second works on computer. I need to implement their communication through the USB port. How I can do it? Where I can I find a good manual about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preamble: I'm not sure that Samsung E250 is Symbian based, but because this topic is marked with symbian tag, here's my answer.

You should use serial port for communications over USB. When your Symbian-based phone is attached to a PC via USB cable in PC Suite mode, virtual COM port is allocated on both sides of connection. In order to use it, refer to http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000601_-_Serial_communication_over_USB_on_S60_3rd_Edition_devices